# .htaccess redirect dynamic url to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `www.olddomain.com/confirm/dynamic_url` 
To `www.newdomain/confirm/same_dynamic_url`

Example 
Everything after/confirm/ is dynamic value and change everytime.

> www.domain1.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM

has to change

> www.domain2.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM

Everything after `/confirm/` is dynamic and change every time.

domain1.com has to be functional when the url has not /confirm/ in and not redirect root.

Example

www.domain1.com/contactus ->No redirect

www.domain1.com/confirm/bla/bla/bla ->redirect

Thanks

Comment: For Temporary redirect use this : 

# 301 Redirect URLs.

Redirect 301 /www.domain1.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM /www.domain2.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM

For permanent redirect use this :

Redirect 301 /confirm www.domain2.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Redirect 301 /confirm www.domain2.com/confirm/cb505b970cf819590ac9488810cb75beeb04335b/1499332181/ahJlfm9mZml0by1hcHBncmVlZHlyFAsSB0FjY291bnQYgICAgNShxwoM
```

Comment: eveything after /confirm/ is dynamic url and change every time

Comment: ok, Let me try again.